# Restrict access to specific  ports

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, port, port-forwarding

I launched keep launching EC2 instances and for some reason i keep getting this email and then the server amazon shuts the server down...How do i restrict access to the port in question...

here is my email

We have detected that your instance(s):

i-acfadec3

have been behaving in the following way that is against our AWS Customer Agreement:

Port Scanning

Please be aware that in terms of the Web Services License Agreement http://aws.amazon.com/agreement/ if your instance(s) continue such abusive behavior, your account may be subject to termination.

EC2 has taken the following administrative action(s) against your instance(s):

THROTTLED OUTBOUND PORT 22

It may be possible that you are not hosting this yourself, but your environment may have been compromised by an external attacker. It remains your responsibility to ensure that your instances and all applications are secured against attack. Furthermore, you should:

- Restrict access to specific and required ports and source addresses using the ’ec2-authorize’ command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple iptable rule for this.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

The above commands will block inbound connections on port 22 both TCP and UDP.

Comment: i got this error iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0 --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables v1.4.4: unknown option `--dport'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: It's probably not supported by your version of iptables. You can try to replace --dport to --destination-port

Comment: here is the new error...iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0 --destination-port 22 -j DROP
iptables v1.4.4: unknown option `--destination-port'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: I've changed the above commands. Hope that it will work now.

Comment: You can also make sure it's working by running iptables -L

Comment: but will that not allow me to ssh in anymore

Comment: You can instruct SSH daemon to use another port. Just edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Then you can use ssh -p <port> for connecting.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like amazon thinks that you are running port scans from your instance, if you are not (and from the sound of it doesnt sound like you are) then there is a possbility that your box has been compromised and is being used to stage attacks to other servers.

Use the `last` command to see if you notice any strange logins, check out /var/log/auth.log. use the `top` command to see if there are any unknown processes running.